# debootstrap not working in kali and mint

Tags: linux, chroot, android, debootstrap

I am trying to install linux in android by chroot method.

Following tutorials available on internet , I tried debootstrap on kali linux and mint. But everytime it returns no output.

`debootstrap --verbose –-arch=arm64 -–foreign jessie ./jessie ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/`

I tried various options but it retuns no output.

Comment: Replace `./jessie` by the mount point e,g: `/mnt/your_mount_point`

Comment: But  ./jessie is the destination location of jessie files where I want to store.  How could it resolve the issue ?

Comment: Thanks . It worked ! . But why and How ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a  mount point then mount the needed partition to install debian e,g: `sdaX`

```
mkdir /mnt/debinst
mount /dev/sdaX /mnt/debinst
```

According to [`man debootstarp`](https://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?sektion=8&query=debootstrap&apropos=0&manpath=sid&locale=en) the format is:

```
debootstrap [OPTION...]  SUITE TARGET [MIRROR [SCRIPT]]
```

in your case should be:

```
debootstrap --verbose –-arch=arm64 -–foreign jessie /mnt/debinst ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/
```

Tuto : [Installing Debian GNU/Linux from a Unix/Linux System](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apds03.html)